# Qt Widgets and derived classes

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, derived-class, qgraphicsview

I am wondering if there is a way to do this.

1. I create a Qt Application (using Creator 3.6.1, Qt 5.6.0).
2. I add a widget to the main window. For example a QGraphicsView called myView.
3. I create a C++ class derived from QGraphicsView (called DerivedView)

code of DerivedView class:

```
class DerivedView : public QGraphicsView {
...
```

I would like my new DerivedView class to control this widget. I can access a pointer to the object through ui->myView. Is there any way to do get my derived class to work with the already instantiated QGraphicsView?

```
DerivedView * dView = ui->myView;
```

Or do I need to not derive my class from QGraphicsView and just add a pointer as a data member?

```
class DerivedView {
    QGraphicsView * gv;
...
```

Comment: since that item is of the super class you could cast it to your class

Comment: You should promote the widget: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-using-custom-widgets.html

Answer (score 3):

You should promote your `QGraphicsView` to `DerivedView`, for this follows the following steps.

Right click on `QGraphicsView` and select `promote to ..`:

[image]

And add the name of the class and header

[image]

And press add.

[image]

And then press on promote. 
After this, `ui->myView` is already a member of the `DerivedView` class

Comment: promote the base class to become a derived class?  I'm confused.  I have a `calculator.ui`, `calcuator.cpp`, `calcuator.h` that I want to use as a base class for my `scientific_calculator.cpp` so promote the calculator class to become a scientific_calculator?

Comment: I mean, rather than a promotion, which I see as a lower derived class promoted to a higher base class, this seems to do the opposite.