# inputMask fills QLineEdit with spaces

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit, input-mask

When I set `inputMask` to "99999" , run program, and mouse clicking to `QLineEdit`, it filled with 5 spaces, so I have to delete the spaces first, and only then put the value I need.

I've tried to set cursor position to 0 ,but it doesn't work. Also tried to set text to empty string, same result.

```
ui->engineCapacity_lineEdit->setInputMask("99999");
ui->engineCapacity_lineEdit->setCursorPosition(0);
ui->engineCapacity_lineEdit->setText("");
```

It suppose to put cursor to the beginning of `lineEdit`, instead it's on 5th character of the line

Comment: @eyllanesc yes, i want cursor be at the begining every time i click QLineEdit, as it happens if there is no inputMask, is there a way? Actually then i use TAB to get into QLineEdit it works as i expect it to, cursor being placed at the begining

Answer (score 1):

By default `QLineEdit` will set the cursor based on the position of the click, and in the case that the number of characters is restricted as in your case and if you press outside the valid sector then the cursor will be placed on the right edge of that sector.

If you want that to happen then you must implement that logic in the `mousePressEvent`:

```
class LineEdit: public QLineEdit
{
public:
    using QLineEdit::QLineEdit;
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
    {
        QLineEdit::mousePressEvent(event);
        setCursorPosition(0);
    }
};
```

If you want to use that `QLineEdit` in your .ui then you must promote it for this you can check the following publications:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-custom-widgets.html
- [Qt Widgets and derived classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577262/qt-widgets-and-derived-classes/41577507#41577507)
- [How to insert QChartView in form with Qt Designer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48362864/how-to-insert-qchartview-in-form-with-qt-designer/48363007#48363007)
- [QCalendarWidget - How to Highlight Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45134809/qcalendarwidget-how-to-highlight-dates/45134976#45134976)

Another way to implement the same logic is using an event filter:

***.h**

```cpp
class YourClass: public Foo{
// ...
public:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);
};
```

***.cpp**

```cpp
    // constructor
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->engineCapacity_lineEdit->installEventFilter(this);
    // ...

bool YourClass::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event){
    if(obj == ui->engineCapacity_lineEdit && event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
    {
        ui->engineCapacity_lineEdit->setCursorPosition(0);
    }
    return Foo::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```